# Capistrano deployment stuck at assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

We are facing an issue with deploying our Rails app using Capistrano from a MacOS machine.

Capistrano runs inside a Docker container.

If I trigger the deployment from a Linux host machine (Capistrano running in Docker), it succeeds on all servers.
However, on MacOS, the deployment to production runs fine but not to the staging server.

The deployment is stuck at:

```
0:28 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I can see on the server that the pre-compilation is running but Capistrano is stuck.

However, when it is run on a Linux machine or a CI server or to Production, it works fine.

```
00:09 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 yarn install v1.22.17
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 warning " > @rails/actiontext@6.1.7" has incorrect peer dependency "trix@^1.2.0".
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 Done in 22.10s.
      01 yarn run v1.22.17
      01 $ RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production} NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production} && webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV} --env RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV} --progress
      01 <s> [webpack.Progress] 0% 
      01 
      01 <s> [webpack.Progress] 1% setup before run
      01 <s> [webpack.Progress] 1% setup before run NodeEnvironmentPlugin
      01 <s> [webpack.Progress] 1% setup before run
```

In all scenarios, Capistrano is running from inside a Docker container.

The problem is only on MacOS and for only one server. Exact same Capistrano config and setup works for production deployments on MacOS.

I'm not sure on how to continue debugging this further and I would be very happy if someone could help and point me into the right direction.

Additionally, if I run Capistrano only for deploy:assets:precompile job, the job runs without any issues and print the output.

------ UPDATE --------

After restarting my development machine, everything seems to work now. It would be helpful to understand why this is the case. Others have also reported similar issues that got fixed after restart.

Comment: I have all my projects working with Capistrano and this seems like a bug to me... Sound like a not professional answer, but most of times solves after rebooting my local machine, did you tried that?

Comment: Maybe try 'config.assets.debug = true' in config/application.rb

Comment: Also maybe a 'rake assets:clobber' in capistrano

Comment: Oddly, restarting the local machine has worked now. It hasn't worked before but it seems to work now.